# Negation of a verb in the "passé Composé" and used with a "COI"

Tags: grammaire, négation, passé-composé

I have a sentence like this:

> Elle a écrit à ses parents?

How can I answer this question? Is it:

1. Non, elle n'a pas lui écrit.
2. Non, elle n'a lui écrit pas.
3. Non, elle ne lui a écrit pas.
4. Non, elle n'a pas lui écrit.
5. Non, elle ne lui a pas écrit.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Number 5 is nearly correct; you need *leur* here, as it means *them* (referring to the parents) as an indirect object pronoun. An indirect object pronoun is used when the verb doesn’t take a direct object (in other words, someone that something is done *to* or *for*). In this case, the subject is writing *to* her parents, which would be *écrire à*.

Therefore:

**Non, elle ne leur a pas écrit.**

Comment: But in past tense , isn’t we put the negation between “a”? ( n’a pas ecrit ) why when it involves coi , it becomes ne leur a ecrit pas instead of ne leur a pas ecrit ?

Comment: That was an error on my part, I apologize. I edited it to reflect the change. You’re right; it is _...ne leur a pas écrit._

Comment: With your change, you should also replace "Number 3 is nearly correct" by "Number 5 is nearly correct".

Comment: @Steph, good call. I know this, too. Not sure why I made the mistake but thanks so much for catching it!

Answer (score 2):

The only proper way to answer is "non, elle ne leur a pas écrit".